# Custom API in PowerApps showing error

Tags: azure, powerapps

I am new to PowerApps. I am trying to connect PowerApps to my custom APIs (Azure app api) and getting this error :

> An error occured while converting swagger file to WADL file. Error:
>   'Unknown swagger type "array" at JSON path paths.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't help with that specific error. I had the same problem when trying to upload a sample swagger file I had.I did, however, have success when uploading my actual swagger file with the use of [Swashbuckle](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/paulballard/give-your-rest-apis-some-metadata-swagger)

Comment: I have used that only. Swashbuckle to generate the swagger file. Even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would load your swagger into https://editor.swagger.io/  and see if you can resolve any errors before using them in powerapps.